# How to save Application theme name in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I am using Devexpress and WPF. There are different themes user can apply provided by devexpress.

```
 ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = Theme.MetropolisDarkName; //MetropolisDarkName is name of a Theme.
```

In my application user can select any theme to apply. But if he closes application and opens it again, Themes changes doesn't same. I want that these changes should be saved so if user after applying theme will open it again, changes should be saved and apply.

Should i have to save name of Theme in database or is there any other way to solve this. I need your suggestions. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can users change just the current theme, or can they change properties of the theme as well?

Comment: only current Theme. @DanielGimenez

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The super easy way to do this in Visual Studio is to add a new `.settings` file to your project, and define a setting of `ThemeName`.  You can find the settings template under `General` in the C# project Templates.  The settings file itself is just a designer with an underlying class of type `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`.

The class created saves setting values to the `app.config`.  The neat thing is you can define settings as application or user, so different users using the application on the same machine can have their own custom settings.

*The following assumes that you created the file `Settings.settings` with an entry called `ThemeName` of type `string`.*

### Get the theme from Settings

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = Properties.Settings.Default.ThemeName;
}
```

### Save the Theme

```
public void SetTheme(string themeName) {
    ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = themeName;
    Properties.Settings.Default.ThemeName = themeName;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

### [Settings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.)

Comment: ok i got it . Sorry and sure i will mark it as answer any will also vote it up as you have defined it in very excellent way . Can you please define me that how to pass value in this function. I mean should i have to call this method/

Comment: now it is saying -- The name 'SetTheme' does not exist in the current context --

Comment: can you please tell me again that where i have to write `Save the Theme Method`